# How to acknowledge websocket (spring websocket + stomp + sockjs) message delivery

Tags: java, spring, stomp, sockjs, spring-websocket

I am creating a simple client-server demo using websockets. In this demo client can subscribe to different topics. Whenever server has anything to send, it will just send the message on the appropriate topic and only subscribed clients will get the same message.

My server should get acknowledgment whenever it sends the message to any topic, but I am little bit confused, how should I get this acknowledgment of the sent message as the sending method returns `void`

below is my **WebSocketConfig** class,

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/testApp");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/message").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

Below is how **topic subscription** happens at client side,

```
var topic = '/testApp/testTopic';
stompClient.subscribe(topic, function(greeting){
});
```

below is how my **server sending message to particular *topic***,

```
 String message = "test message";
 this.template.convertAndSend(topic, new Chat(message));
```

above method(i.e. `this.template.convertAndSend(topic, new Chat(message));`) returns `void`

at the end I am able to successfully send message to all/particular subscribed client but don't know how to get assure whether the message is successfully delivered at the other end or not?

Comment: Are you able solved this ?

Comment: @Bhushan, Ah, the tale of the elusive ticket! It was like a puzzle lost in the labyrinth of priorities and projects, weaving through the threads of my backend days. Just when I thought I was close, it slipped away into the abyss of shifting job roles and a new company horizon. Perhaps that ticket found a new home in the land of forgotten bugs, where it now tells stories of the backend days to other lost tickets, forever wandering in the realms of the unknown...